# Basis of the vector space of real polynomials of maximum degree n.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Studying affine geometry, I came across an example for a basis of the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of all real polynomials of maximum degree n. If $\mathbb{R}_{n}[t]=\{f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} / f(t)=a_{0}+a_{1}t+...+a_{n}t^{n}\}$ is this set, then the set $\{1,t,t^{2},...,t^{n}\}$ is a basis of the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $(\mathbb{R}_{n}[t],+,*)$ where $+$ is the common addition between polynomials and also $*$ is the scalar multiplication between real numbers and polynomials.
I wondered if there were any vector subspaces of this vector space and found that $\mathcal{E}_{0}=\{f\in \mathbb{R}_{n}[t]/ \int_0^1f(t)dt=0\}$ is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}_{n}[t]$. However I couldn't find a basis for this vector space. I am sure that every polynomial that belongs to this vector subspace, will be either the null polynomial or have at least one root inside $(0,1)$ as if it wasn't for these cases, $f$ would be only negative or only positive in the interval $(0,1)$ and $\int_0^1f(t)dt \neq0$ which is a contradiction.I found also that $f(t)=(n+1)t^{n}-(n)t^{n-1} \in \mathcal{E}_{0}$. Any idea in how to think to create a basis?

Comment: I now think that maybe there is not even a polynomial with irrational roots greater than $0$ and less than $1$ in $\mathcal{E}_{0}$ as it seems that the form of polynomial I give has a root of $(n)/(n+1)$. But only if the set is generated from this kind of polynomials.

Comment: The polynomials you wrote at the end of your question form such a basis.

Comment: You mean the set of all these polynomials for the different values of $n$ ?

Comment: Yes, the polynomials $(k+1)t^k-kt^{k-1}$ with $k=1,2,\ldots,n$.